# Struggles with Winter 13 Push Major Upgrade - Doesn't seem possible to push a major upgrade

Tags: managed-package, push-upgrade

I am struggling with the Push Major Upgrade feature in WI 13.

Scenario:

- Some subscribers with v1.3 and some with v1.4.
- I want to push upgrade all customers from 1.3 to 1.4
- I have major version 1.4 ready to ship.
- There is a patch v1.4.1 in the DE org as well

The v1.4.1 was created while following the release notes instructions in WI 13 release. It read like you could only push an upgrade after you create a patch version. I find the release notes lacking detail around a push **major** upgrade scenario. It seems the focus is still on push patch upgrades which is NOT a new feature.

When I try to push an upgrade from the DE org, the only option under the Schedule Push Upgrade is v1.4.1. It seems I am not able to push 1.4 to my subscribers with 1.3. I can only push v1.4.1. Is there some rule or limit that allows only the most recent version # to be eligible for a push?

SFDC partner support has not been helpful. They simply point you at the same release notes i've read a few hundred times now... Community: please help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a case and ask them to turn Push Major Upgrade on.  It is not enabled by default.  It is still in Pilot at this point.

Comment: Is there a difference between pushing major and minor updates?

Comment: Yes - we just found out that you have to request MAJOR separately.

Comment: Also it appears you can't upgrade from one major version to a patch release of another major version as one action.  So to push an upgrade from 2.0 to 2.1.1 you'd have to first push the upgrade to 2.1 then push another upgrade to 2.1.1.  Hopefully they change that in the future.